# Laravel 9 validation - distinct not working

Tags: laravel, validation

Hello i'm trying to use the distinct rule in validation to avoid duplicated values of the array. I didn't really get how it works by the documentation. My validation is not working.

Basically i need to check the values of 'codice_articolo' that mustn't be duplicated

```
    $row = 9;  
    while ($worksheet->getCell("A$row")->getValue() !== NULL) {
        $newEntry = [];    
        $newEntry['codice_articolo'] = $worksheet->getCell("A$row")->getValue();  
        $newEntry['quantita'] = $worksheet->getCell("B$row")->getValue();       
        $newEntry['prezzo'] = $worksheet->getCell("C$row")->getValue();
        $data_detail[] = $newEntry;  
        $row++;
    }
    dump($newEntry);
    dd($data_detail);
```

[image]

```
        $validator_detail = Validator::make($newEntry, [
        'codice_articolo.*' => 'required|distinct|max:25',
        'quantita' => 'required|max:10',
        'prezzo' => 'required|numeric',
        
    ], [
        'max' => 'Massimo :max caratteri permessi per ":Attribute"',
        'required' => ':Attribute è obbligatorio!',
        'distinct' => ':Attribute non deve essere duplicato!',
        'numeric' => 'Il prezzo deve essere in formato numerico'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any nested attributes of `codice_articolo`. Try changing `'codice_articolo.*'` to just `'codice_articolo'` in your validator.

Comment: Tried even before but, it's not validating both ways

Answer (score 0):

You have used array in request.
so for array validation use like this :

```
$validator = Validator::make($newEntry, [
        '*.codice_articolo' => 'required|distinct|max:25',
        '*.quantita' => 'required|max:10|numeric',
        '*.prezzo' => 'required|numeric',

    ], [
        'max' => 'Massimo :max caratteri permessi per ":Attribute"',
        'required' => ':Attribute è obbligatorio!',
        'distinct' => ':Attribute non deve essere duplicato!',
        'numeric' => 'Il prezzo deve essere in formato numerico'
    ]);
```

may it helps.

Comment: no that only triplicated same error for each key

Comment: it's okay. duplicate validation gives same error at both the same value's key.
ex : if there is three key having same value than it will give same error at all the three keys.

Comment: Ok but i only have to validate 'codice_articolo' that mustn't accept duplicated values, as shown in the dump screen.

Comment: Just now i chanched Validator::make($newEntry, ... to $data_detail, [ *.codice_articolo' => 'required|distinct|max:25',] ... by this way i get the expected error for each array key > 0.codice_articolo non deve essere duplicato!
1.codice_articolo non deve essere duplicato! .. If you want to review the answer i mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

try
'codice_articolo'

instead of
'codice_articolo.*'

//or use
unique:xxxx